# When solving via gauss-jordan

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

When I solve via Gauss-Jordan, taking a $3 \times3$ matrix as an example...

Should I always try and get a $1$ in the upper left corner and $0$'s in the rest of the column followed by getting a $1$ in the middle $2^{\text{nd}}$ column, $2^{\text{nd}}$ row followed by $0$'s in the $2^{\text{nd}}$ column and then finally get a $1$ in the bottom-right corner followed by $0$'s in the $3^{\text{rd}}$ column?

Is this THE system to solve these or does it just vary? Could I be trying to get $1\ 0\ 0$ in the first row for example and work rows like that?

Comment: Gaussian elimination is the name of a particular algorithm. There could be minor differences in how it's performed, but in general _yes_, that's the system (which is not to say that alternative methods don't exist). How would you work by rows anyways?

Comment: I just want to be sure that what I am doing is the correct way, seeing as I often end up stuck.

Comment: If you're doing it correctly, Gaussian elimination always brings the matrix into row echelon form. Could you perhaps post an example where you get stuck? I suspect that there is a mistake in how you're performing the procedure somewhere.

Comment: Inverting thix matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
        0,3 & 0,3 & 0,1 \\
        0,1 & 0,1 & 0,1 \\
        0,2 & 0,2 & 0,1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

Gets me stuck at:

$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & -2 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

When I invert it, I do Gauss-Jordan with the identity matrix, but I don't know how to do that with tex code.

Comment: Basically, I just multiplied the matrix by 10, swapped row 2 and 1, multiplied row 1 by minus 3 and minus 2 respectively and replaced that with row 2 and 3.

Comment: Your matrix is not invertible. That's probably why you're getting stuck. The first and second columns are the same, this necessarily means the matrix is non-invertible.

Comment: That's funny. This problem was a part of a Leontief input-output model in last year's finals. Oh, well, that clears that up. Thank you.

Comment: If it's any reassurance, you did perform the row reduction correctly. The Reduced Row Echelon Form of the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ which is what you would've obtained if you had carried the Gauss-Jordan elimination to its completion.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the $3\times3$ case, you only need to get it in the form
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & d \\
        0 & c & e \\
        0 & 0 & f \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
This is called an upper triangluar matrix.  When you are solving the system $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$, this allows you to solve the system by substitution.  If $\mathbf{b}=(1 1 1)^T$, for example, then $fz=1$ which implies that $z=\frac1{f}$.  Now you can back substitute in row 2 and solve for y, and then back substitute again and solve for x.  Solving in this way allows us the substitution method for solving systems of equations.  It would be easier to solve though if our matrix was in the form
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & a & b \\
        0 & 1 & c \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
since now there is no dividing by the coefficient to get $x$, say.  Finally, you can understand why it is so efficient to put the system into RREF, or reduced row echelon form which is
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
or something similar to this depending on the dependence of the vectors involved since then it is easy to see that, in our $(1 1 1)^T$ example that $x=1, y=1,$ and $z=1$.  I hope this helps.